# How to search in WordPress content instead of title only

Tags: wordpress, search

I'm using the following query/code for a custom WordPress search-plugin.

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_like_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function title_like_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $post_title_like = $wp_query->get( 'post_title_like' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $post_title_like ) ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

But it is only searching in the post-titles, where I want it to search in both the title and the content.
If I simply change the word 'title' with the word 'content', it doesn't work.

Anyone knows what I have to do in order to make the query search in both the title and the content?

Comment: I think I'm able to search in both title and content if I can add a 'OR' in my query.

$where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $post_title_like ) ) . '%\''

Can someone tell me how to add the 'OR' in this line? (post_title OR post_content LIKE x)